# is it legal to merge multiple database transactions together?

Tags: database, transactions, relational-database

I am wondering if it is always legal to merge multiple database transactions together? Would that break program semantics in any way?

Comment: Can you provide more information? What DB system are you using? What have you tried? What language/framework are you working with? We're going need more information to give a proper answer.

Comment: "Merge multiple transactions" is vague and "break program semantics" is general so if you want to avoid waiting until someone writes you a precis on concurrency then you could clearly describe your particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that we're talking about three transactions. And let's make some sensible assumptions: the final result of both ways is identical, there are no side-effects, etc.

The difference between the three separate transactions and a single merged transaction has to do with database states. After each of the three separate transactions is committed, the database is in a consistent state. And each of those committed states is visible to *other* concurrent transactions.

After the single, merged transaction is committed, there's a single consistent state. If there are intermediate consistent states, they're *not* visible to other transactions.

The transaction isolation level affects the details a little, but that's the essential difference.